# Rank of a matrix with an added all-1 row

Tags: linear-algebra

As part of a proof I have the following statement, $A$ being an $n × n$ matrix:

> Let us assume that $rank(A) ≤ n − 2$. If we add an extra row consisting of all $1$s to $A$, the resulting $(n+1) × n$ matrix still has rank at most $n − 1$.

I don't understand how adding an extra row can *reduce* the rank of a matrix.

Comment: it increases from $n-2$ to $n-1$.

Comment: Oho, thanks. Now that was dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ has $r$ linearly independent rows $R_1,\ldots ,R_r$ and $r\leq n-2$. Let $R$ be the row of all $1$'s. Now if $R_1,\ldots ,R_r , R$ are linearly independent, then the rank becomes $r+1$ and if they are linearly dependent then rank is $r$. So in either case rank is $\leq r+1\leq n-1$.